# How to properly kill a service upon shutdown?

Tags: fedora, systemd, services, matlab

I am having some issues with a component that I have installed recently, that is Matlab Drive Connector for Linux Fedora 37.

The app itself works fine, interacts well with main Matlab program, but it annoys me very much upon shutdown of my machine.
Seems like this application relies on a service that `systemd` can't properly terminate when I shutdown or reboot. Luckily there's a time limit after which the system forcefully terminates the service.

An easy fix would be to manually stop the service using the application itself, running `MATLABConnector stop`, but I sometimes forget to type it in before shutdown.

Any idea on how I can fix this issue? Having `MATLABConnector stop` run automatically before shutdown would solve the issue, but I honestly have no clue on how to perform that.

Comment: Make the command run automatically on shutdown. Instructions are easily found, for example https://opensource.com/life/16/11/running-commands-shutdown-linux

Comment: This is not open source software - i.e. you are probably paying for support from people whom are more capable of answering your query than we are. While it would be trivial to write a systemd unit file to handle the case, it depends on a lot more information than you have provided here. e.g. does "MATLABConnector stop" have to be run as the user who started it?